# How do I convert a varchar field into the datetime data type?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, select, converters

```
SELECT * 
FROM `travail` 
WHERE Convert(datetime, `dateReception`)=(datetime, '01/01/2014' )
```

The value of `dateReception` is 2014-01-01 but it's a varchar not date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**STR_TO_DATE()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function:

```
SELECT * 
FROM travail 
WHERE DATE(dateReception) = STR_TO_DATE('01/01/2014', '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: He said that `dateReception` is in YYYY-MM-DD format, not DD/MM/YYYY format

Answer (score 2):

If your varchar is like this:

```
8/11/2011 20:14 PM
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('8/11/2011 20:14 PM', '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s')
```

Comment: he said his varchar is like 2014-01-01, why do you think it might be like that?